# Is it possible get table structures of a .frm file using PHP?

Tags: php

In MySQL I have seen there are .frm files which contains the structure of the table.

Is it possible get the table structures of a .frm file using PHP?

Comment: To make this a bit more reliable... any chance of importing it into a temporary database and letting MySQL read it?  Or is that file damaged?

Comment: @Brad He did not say why he wanted to read the .frm. I agree people sometimes get away with restoring the .frm from a backup if the table is corrupted, but that is just lucky!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes.

.frm files are like any other file and you can open it and read its contents with PHP.

The format of .frm files is quite complex so you need to be familiar with it, before you can do anything useful. This format is described here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/frm-file-format.html

You can read a .frm file and determine whatever metadata about the table you need, such as column details, indexing etc.

Comment: The file_get_contents() can't provide the simplified understandable data. Can it be got by any PHP method?

Comment: @Abu Saleh Muhammad Zakaria The .frm files are meant for internal mySQL use and not really meant for PHP programs to read. If you need to read metadata about a database or tables you can query the system tables of for this. Much easier. What are you trying to achieve with your program?

Comment: @Abu Saleh Muhammad Zakaria For example you can make a query like this to find the columns of a table. **SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  WHERE table_name = 'tableName';**

Comment: Sorry to say that I want to read it without query or phpMyAdmin...
Suppose I have a separate .frm file. How can I read it by PHP?

Comment: @Abu Saleh Muhammad Zakaria OK please pose a new stackflow question asking for a PHP code sample to read say the column names for a mySQL "tablename".frm file and I will reply.  Also consider that you can write SQL queries in PHP that can read the same information from the information_schema as per previous comment. Please help by saying what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Here is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51852099/